# PHP empty key in array

Tags: php, arrays

In PHP, is there a function for finding the lowest numerical key without a value in an array? I have an array like this:

```
array (
    0 => 'nested array',
    1 => 'nested array',
    2 => 'nested array',
    3 => 'nested array',
    6 => 'nested array',
    7 => 'nested array',
)
```

and I would like to add a value to this array (at `4`), not necessarily unique, and get its position back without altering the rest of the keys. Is the easiest way to loop through the array and test `isset()`, or is there an easier way?

Comment: Generate the keys you expect with `range`, then find the lowest missing one. `$expected_keys = range(0, count($your_array) - 1); $missing_keys = array_diff($expected_keys, array_keys($your_array)); return min($missing_keys);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try the following to search for the lowest key:

```
$arr = array (
    0 => 'nested array',
    1 => 'nested array',
    2 => 'nested array',
    3 => 'nested array',
    6 => 'nested array',
    7 => 'nested array',
);

// get a list of existing keys
$keys = array_keys($arr);

// get the min and max keys
$min = min($keys);
$max = max($keys);

// get the missing keys by:
// * creating a range from the existing min/max
// *diff it from the list of actual keys
$missing = array_diff(range($min, $max), $keys);

// get the min missing key from the diff
echo min($missing);
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: **+1** for the easy way.

Comment: +1 for the comments. Not to be pedantic, but I think you should rename `$key` to `$keys` ;)

Comment: How is this any easier than looping to find an available key?

Comment: hi @salathe - I assume you're addressing Shankar with that question. I don't think it is necessarily, there's more than one way to skin a cat I suppose :) I personally have nothing against a loop, this is just my approach.

Comment: @Darragh I was addressing you, since the question is asking for the "easiest" way.

Answer (score 3):

> In PHP, is there a function for finding the lowest numerical key without a value in an array?

No.

> Is the easiest way to loop through the array and test isset()

Looping is okay, but [`isset()`](http://php.net/isset) isn't going to be the best choice.  It could raise a false-positive where an array key exists but contains a `NULL` value.  A better choice would be [`array_key_exists()`](http://php.net/array_key_exists).

In your case, a loop can be as *simple* as:

```
for ($key = 0; array_key_exists($key, $arr); $key++);
var_dump($key);
```

> or is there an easier way?

See the other answers suggesting alternatives, which may or may not be *easier*.

Answer (score 0):

This works -

```
function find_empty($arr){
    foreach(range(0,max(array_keys($arr))) as $i){
        if(!array_key_exists($i, $arr)){
            return $i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Testing it -

```
$arr = array (
    0 => 'nested array',
    1 => 'nested array',
    2 => 'nested array',
    3 => 'nested array',
    6 => 'nested array',
    7 => 'nested array',
);
var_dump(find_empty($arr));
/**
OUTPUT
int 4
**/
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this. I think it looks cool, but I wouldn't do it, because it's not very efficient:

```
$array = array(0 => 'x', 1 => 'x', 2 => 'x', 4 => 'x', 7 => 'x');

$indexes = array_keys($array); // 0, 1, 2, 4, 7
// sort($array, SORT_NUMERIC);
$all_indexes = range($indexes[0], $indexes[count($indexes)-1]); // 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7
$missing_indexes = array_diff($all_indexes, $indexes); // 3, 5, 6
print_r($missing_indexes);

$lowest = reset($missing_indexes);
$highest = end($missing_indexes);
var_dump($lowest, $highest);
```

You can compact it in many less lines if that's your thing.

You now have all the missing index information: how many, which, lowest, highest, average etc

Comment: I'd rather use `min()` and `max()` to get the minimum and maximum values (you don't need the `sort()` that way).

Answer (score 0):

You can get an array of all open keys by using `range()` and `array_diff` along with `array_keys`:

```
$array = array (
    0 => 'nested array',
    1 => 'nested array',
    2 => 'nested array',
    3 => 'nested array',
    6 => 'nested array',
    7 => 'nested array',
);

$array_keys = array_keys($array);
sort($array_keys);

$min_key = 0;
$max_key = end($array_keys);

$array_key_range = range($min_key, $max_key);

$open_keys = array_diff($array_key_range , $array_keys);
```

You can then use the first value in that array as the lowest, or any, if you just want to find an open slot.